# Sql Value change after the dot

Tags: sql, function, t-sql, scalar

I am trying to change values after the dot. Custom rounding. I am passing an argument into the function(should be real value but can I use varchar?)
In this example I am trying varchar with substring but this makes conversion error.
Can someone tell me what methods Could I use to achieve my result? Maybe real data type value? But can then I use substring?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Myfunction
(
    @Liczba varchar(255)
)
RETURNS varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    if @Liczba >= 0 and @Liczba < 7 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) >= 0 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) <= 24
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 1) + (0.19));
    if @Liczba >= 0 and @Liczba < 7 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) >= 25 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) <= 34
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 1) + (0.29));
    if @Liczba >= 0 and @Liczba < 7 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) >= 35 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) <= 44
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 1) + (0.39));
    if @Liczba >= 0 and @Liczba < 7 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) >= 45 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) <= 54
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 1) + (0.49));
    if @Liczba >= 0 and @Liczba < 7 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) >= 55 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) <= 64
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 1) + (0.59));
    if @Liczba >= 0 and @Liczba < 7 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) >= 65 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) <= 74
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 1) + (0.69));
    if @Liczba >= 0 and @Liczba < 7 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) >= 75 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) <= 88
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 1) + (0.79));
    if @Liczba >= 0 and @Liczba < 7 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) >= 89 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) <= 99
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 1) + (0.99));

    if @Liczba >= 7 and @Liczba < 10 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) >= 0 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) <= 38
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 1) + (0.29));
    if @Liczba >= 7 and @Liczba < 10 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) >= 39 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) <= 63
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 1) + (0.49));
    if @Liczba >= 7 and @Liczba < 10 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) >= 64 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) <= 88
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 1) + (0.79));
    if @Liczba >= 7 and @Liczba < 10 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) >= 89 and substring(@Liczba, 3, 2) <= 99
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 1) + (0.99));

    if @Liczba >= 10 and @Liczba < 15 and substring(@Liczba, 4, 2) >= 0 and substring(@Liczba, 4, 2) <= 38
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 2) + (0.29));
    if @Liczba >= 10 and @Liczba < 15 and substring(@Liczba, 4, 2) >= 39 and substring(@Liczba, 4, 2) <= 63
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 2) + (0.49));
    if @Liczba >= 10 and @Liczba < 15 and substring(@Liczba, 4, 2) >= 64 and substring(@Liczba, 4, 2) <= 88
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 2) + (0.79));
    if @Liczba >= 10 and @Liczba < 15 and substring(@Liczba, 4, 2) >= 89 and substring(@Liczba, 4, 2) <= 99
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 2) + (0.99));

    if @Liczba >= 15 and @Liczba < 30 and substring(@Liczba, 4, 2) >= 0 and substring(@Liczba, 4, 2) <= 49
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 2) + (0.49));
    if @Liczba >= 15 and @Liczba < 30 and substring(@Liczba, 4, 2) >= 50 and substring(@Liczba, 4, 2) <= 99
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 2) + (0.99));

    if @Liczba >= 30 and @Liczba < 100 and substring(@Liczba, 4, 2) >= 0 and substring(@Liczba, 4, 2) <= 99
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 2) + (0.99));
    if @Liczba >= 30 and @Liczba < 100 and substring(@Liczba, 4, 2) >= 0 and substring(@Liczba, 4, 2) <= 99
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 3) + (0.99));
    if @Liczba >= 100 and @Liczba < 1000 and substring(@Liczba, 5, 2) >= 0 and substring(@Liczba, 5, 2) <= 99
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 4) + (0.99));
    if @Liczba >= 1000 and @Liczba < 10000 and substring(@Liczba, 6, 2) >= 0 and substring(@Liczba, 6, 2) <= 99
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 5) + (0.99));
    if @Liczba >= 10000 and @Liczba < 100000 and substring(@Liczba, 7, 2) >= 0 and substring(@Liczba, 7, 2) <= 99
        Return (substring(@Liczba, 0, 6) + (0.99));

    Return (@Liczba);
END
```

[image]

Comment: this must be also a homework, as i seen this code already yersteday

Comment: Don't repost your (closed) questions; there is is an edit feature. Use said feature to improve your question and get it reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Where you compare the varchar with the int values i think you get ther errors:

```
 if @Liczba >= 0 and @Liczba < 7 ...
```

i think you should cast here the variable as a float so, but to not repeat the code more then one time i would create a new variable as so:

```
SET @Liczba_float=CAST( @Liczba AS DECIMAL(10,2));
```

and then using it like so where i compare it to a number

```
 if @Liczba_float >= 0 and @Liczba_float < 7 ...
```